# Gradle lib plugins directory

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle

When I download gradle what job does *gradleX.Y/lib/plugins* directory?
What is her task for what or where are those plugins in this library used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of any task specifically. It is created by Gradle itself as part of its distribution.

See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/distributions-integ-tests/src/integTest/groovy/org/gradle/DistributionIntegrationSpec.groovy#L57